# Mapping from many-to-one in Entity Framework Core using AutoMapper

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have two model clsases to get comments list contain full name:

```
public partial class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comment{ get; set; }
    public int? AddBy{ get; set; }
    public virtual User { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments{ get; set; }
}
```

This my Comment Dto

```
public partial class CommentDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

My query selects all comments with user (full name) but include in mapper not given the user model

```
CreateMap<Comment, CommentDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x
```

Comment: `x => x.User.FullName`  - that's what navigation properties are for. Just make sure you use `ProjectTo` and not `Map`.

Comment: Rename the property into `UserFullName`, remove the `.ForMember` part and see AutoMapper's magic happen.